# Uploading to azure blob storage via front end

Tags: javascript, django, azure, post, azure-blob-storage

I want to allow the user to upload large files to azure blob storage.. The problem is when I do it the regular way:

[Javascript HTTP POST Request (with file attached) -> django web server -> azure blob storage]

the request times out..

Is there a way I can have Javascript call and upload photos to azure blob storage directly and securely and skip the django web server?

Comment: Please provide your code(excluding sensitive information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You should use what is known as a valet key pattern. [image]

1. Your client will request a SAS Token from your Django web server. Django web server will connect to azure blog and generate a SAS Token and return that back to Client.

below is example code you can use in python to generate sas token.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas

account_name = 'YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME'
account_key = 'YOUR_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY'
container_name = 'YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME'
blob_name = 'YOUR_BLOB_NAME'

sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name=account_name,
    container_name=container_name,
    blob_name=blob_name,
    account_key=account_key,
    permission=BlobSasPermissions(write=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

print(sas_token)
```

2. your javascript client will then upload the file to blob using sas token directly.

On the client side, you can use the Azure Blob Storage JavaScript SDK to upload files using the generated SAS token:

```js
const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");

const sasToken = "YOUR_GENERATED_SAS_TOKEN"; // Get this from your server
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net?${sasToken}`);

async function uploadFile(file) {
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    await blockBlobClient.uploadBrowserData(file, { blockSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024, concurrency: 20 }); // Adjust parameters as needed
}

// Call the function
const fileInput = document.getElementById("fileInput");
fileInput.addEventListener("change", async (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    await uploadFile(file);
});
```

A Full working example but with C# Backend.
https://github.com/cfe84/demo-storage-valet-key